# Why can't I install Git for Windows with OpenSSH?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, git, tortoise-git

Whenever I try to install Git for Windows, using the installer downloaded from here, the installation seemingly skips the step where I configure my Secure Shell client for Git.

Normally during installation, a screen prompting the user to choose one of either OpenSSH (installed with Git) or PuTTY PLink (the default option) is shown. With my latest few installs, this screen is nowhere to be found. Instead, Git seems to be silently configured to use PLink without any input from me.

**Can anyone tell me why this is happening?**

If I cannot choose which SSH client to use at installation, can anyone tell me how to reconfigure Git to point to OpenSSH instead of TortoisePLink?

This seems to controlled by a Git environment variable (mine reads "GIT_SSH=c:\Program Files\Putty\plink.exe" as opposed to "GIT_SSH=ssh.exe" as it does on another PC with Git working).

**As a work around, does anyone know how to change this variable?**

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this before. Much needs to be done to switch to OpenSSH.

1. Edit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\setup.ini` and REMOVE the following lines (IF they are in the file):

   ```
   GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe
   SVN_SSH=C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe
   ```
2. Edit  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\profile` and REMOVE the line

   ```
   export PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh
   ```
3. Make sure you have an SSH private key file. File is in OpenSSH format NOT in PuTTY private key format, `.ppk`.
4. Create a `.ssh` directory for the Git user and copy the `id_rsa`  file there.

   ```
   md c:\Users\Git_User\.ssh
   ```
5. Open a DOS command Window and type in the command

   ```
   set | more
   ```

   Look for `GIT_SSH` and `SVN_SSH`
6. If found, this indicates that it is configured in the Windows Environmental variables. You will need to remove it from there.

From the Start Menu, open the Control Panel

- Select *User Accounts*
- Select *Change my environment variables*
- Highlight *GIT_SSH ...*
- Click on <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Click on <kbd>OK</kbd>

Repeat this for SVN_SSH.

On my machine, doing these operations DISABLES TortoiseGit.  It might be better to fix your Git config to use `TortoiseGitPlink.exe`.  There is also a `TortoisePlink.exe` in the `TortoiseGit/bin` directory - don't use it. `TortoisePlink.exe` does NOT work for me.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, I don't have the offending PC's with me anymore, do I can't test this, but I will try this next time I encounter the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this tonight and the info from the last poster has since become outdated - but it led me to the right place - basically hiding any notion of putty/plink in your system from the git installer.

Git kept trying to "help" by noticing plink was installed and refused to install openssh.

- Uninstall Git.
- Blow away the leftover structure c:\program files\git.
- Go to your USER registry key, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham

  - Temporarily rename the key to something like SSSSimonTatham (lead with an 'S' so it doesn't sort on you and you can find it quickly later)
- Now Install Git.  (It won't notice you have plink installed)
- Make sure to add the ssh.exe (now installed) to your path

  - For me it was C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
- Rename your putty registry key back to SimonTatham